# Do problems have to be statable in $\Pi_1$ to use Levin's universal search to find short proofs if P=NP

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, proof-complexity, descriptive-complexity, automated-theorem-proving

In [If P=NP, could we obtain proofs of Goldbach's Conjecture etc.?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/if-p-np-could-we-obtain-proofs-of-goldbachs-conjecture-etc) it talks about the hypothetical world where P=NP and using the proof of it to prove a problem/theorem assuming that it has a short proof.

But what exactly is the restriction imposed on problems/theorems? Do they have to be describable in $\Pi_1$ to use Levin's universal search?

If so, can the question like Navier-Stokes existence and smoothness problem be statble in $\Pi_1$?

Comment: The only thing that matters is that the given proof system (in this case, ZFC or similar) has polynomial-time recognizable proofs. The complexity of the statement being proved is irrelevant.

Comment: If downvoting, please also consider suggesting how you think the question could be improved.

Comment: @usul, I think the first part is answered by Emil's comment (I feel it was clear in the original post). The second part about logical complexity of stating a mathematical statement seems more suitable for [math.se] or [mathoverflow.se].